# Adding missing dates to dataframe

Tags: r, date, dataframe, rows

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
    times                      values
1   2013-07-06 20:00:00        0.02
2   2013-07-07 20:00:00        0.03
3   2013-07-09 20:00:00        0.13
4   2013-07-10 20:00:00        0.12
5   2013-07-11 20:00:00        0.03
6   2013-07-14 20:00:00        0.06
7   2013-07-15 20:00:00        0.08
8   2013-07-16 20:00:00        0.07
9   2013-07-17 20:00:00        0.08
```

There are a few dates missing from the data, and I would like to insert them and to carry over the value from the previous day into these new rows, i.e. obtain this:

```
    times                      values
1   2013-07-06 20:00:00        0.02
2   2013-07-07 20:00:00        0.03
3   2013-07-08 20:00:00        0.03
4   2013-07-09 20:00:00        0.13
5   2013-07-10 20:00:00        0.12
6   2013-07-11 20:00:00        0.03
7   2013-07-12 20:00:00        0.03
8   2013-07-13 20:00:00        0.03
9   2013-07-14 20:00:00        0.06
10  2013-07-15 20:00:00        0.08
11  2013-07-16 20:00:00        0.07
12  2013-07-17 20:00:00        0.08
...
```

I have been trying to use a vector of all the dates:

```
dates <- as.Date(1:length(df),origin = df$times[1])
```

I am stuck, and can't find a way to do it without a horrible for loop in which I'm getting lost...
Thank you for your help

Comment: Can I ask why you want to carry over the value from the previous day? It should probably be NA, otherwise you are filling your table with "fake" data which may be an issue in many cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some test data (I am using `Date`, yours seems to be a different type, but this does not affect the algorithm):

```
data = data.frame(dates = as.Date(c("2011-12-15", "2011-12-17", "2011-12-19")), 
                  values = as.double(1:3))

# Generate **all** timestamps at which you want to have your result. 
# I use `seq`, but you may use any other method of generating those timestamps. 

alldates = seq(min(data$dates), max(data$dates), 1)

# Filter out timestamps that are already present in your `data.frame`:
# Construct a `data.frame` to append with missing values:
dates0 = alldates[!(alldates %in% data$dates)]
data0 = data.frame(dates = dates0, values = NA_real_)

# Append this `data.frame` and resort in time:
data = rbind(data, data0)
data = data[order(data$dates),]

# forward fill the values 
# I would recommend to move this code into a separate `ffill` function: 
# proved to be very useful in general):
current = NA_real_
data$values = sapply(data$values, function(x) { 
           current <<- ifelse(is.na(x), current, x); current })
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `tidyr`'s `complete` and `fill` assuming the `times` columns is already of class `POSIXct`.

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  complete(times = seq(min(times), max(times), by = 'day')) %>%
  fill(values)

# A tibble: 12 x 2
#   times               values
#   <dttm>               <dbl>
# 1 2013-07-06 20:00:00   0.02
# 2 2013-07-07 20:00:00   0.03
# 3 2013-07-08 20:00:00   0.03
# 4 2013-07-09 20:00:00   0.13
# 5 2013-07-10 20:00:00   0.12
# 6 2013-07-11 20:00:00   0.03
# 7 2013-07-12 20:00:00   0.03
# 8 2013-07-13 20:00:00   0.03
# 9 2013-07-14 20:00:00   0.06
#10 2013-07-15 20:00:00   0.08
#11 2013-07-16 20:00:00   0.07
#12 2013-07-17 20:00:00   0.08
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(times = structure(c(1373140800, 1373227200, 1373400000, 
1373486400, 1373572800, 1373832000, 1373918400, 1374004800, 1374091200
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), values = c(0.02, 
0.03, 0.13, 0.12, 0.03, 0.06, 0.08, 0.07, 0.08)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 5):

```
library(zoo)
g <- data.frame(dates=seq(min(data$dates),max(data$dates),1))
na.locf(merge(g,data,by="dates",all.x=TRUE))
```

or entirely with zoo:

```
z <- read.zoo(data)
gz <- zoo(, seq(min(time(z)), max(time(z)), "day"))  # time grid in zoo
na.locf(merge(z, gz))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 <- data.frame(times=seq(min(df$times), max(df$times), by="day"))
df3 <- merge(x=df2, y=df, by="times", all.x=T)
idx <- which(is.na(df3$values))
for (id in idx) 
  df3$values[id] <- df3$values[id-1]
df3
#                  times values
# 1  2013-07-06 20:00:00   0.02
# 2  2013-07-07 20:00:00   0.03
# 3  2013-07-08 20:00:00   0.03
# 4  2013-07-09 20:00:00   0.13
# 5  2013-07-10 20:00:00   0.12
# 6  2013-07-11 20:00:00   0.03
# 7  2013-07-12 20:00:00   0.03
# 8  2013-07-13 20:00:00   0.03
# 9  2013-07-14 20:00:00   0.06
# 10 2013-07-15 20:00:00   0.08
# 11 2013-07-16 20:00:00   0.07
# 12 2013-07-17 20:00:00   0.08
```

Comment: `merge`is good! The loop is wrong for the case of consecutive NAs and for the case of a leading NA. The loop will also be very slow on a large data set (see my solution)

Comment: Hey @OlegS. , thanks for the feedback. Agreed, your solution is much faster - nice1. But I can't see the logical prob with the `for` loop here (?). I blame it on Laphroaig.

Comment: sorry, my bad -- you are right: generally the loop will be fine albeit slow, but the problem of the leading NA remains (partially), i.e. if the first value is NA then the first `id` is 1 and the index `id-1` is invalid for 1-based R vectors. Well, I guess R will return an NA in this case, but I would consider it bad practice to program that way.

Comment: The 1st value is always `min(data$dates)`, so this is no problem either. The loop works, but it's too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
   setkey(NADayWiseOrders, date)
   all_dates <- seq(from = as.Date("2013-01-01"), 
               to = as.Date("2013-01-07"), 
               by = "days")

  NADayWiseOrders[J(all_dates), roll=Inf]
     date orders  amount guests
  1: 2013-01-01     50 2272.55    149
  2: 2013-01-02      3   64.04      4
  3: 2013-01-03      3   64.04      4
  4: 2013-01-04      1   18.81      0
  5: 2013-01-05      2   77.62      0
  6: 2013-01-06      2   77.62      0
  7: 2013-01-07      2   35.82      2
```